# My drawn object doesn't clear previous rectangle after key is pressed

Tags: java, user-interface

My code will not clear the previous rectangle when I press one of the arrow keys. I thought that by using `repaint()` in my `keyPressed()` method, that would solve the problem. I also tried using `clearRect()`, but that doesn't do anything.

This is the idle rectangle: [image: http://imgur.com/D9orK9F]

This is when I hold down the right arrow key: [image]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.Icon;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Rectangle extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

private int height;
private int width;
private int x;
private int y;
private Graphics2D g2;



public Rectangle(int width, int height,int x, int y)
{
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.addKeyListener(this);
    label.setFocusable(true);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.addKeyListener(this);
    this.add(label);
    label.requestFocusInWindow();
    setVisible(true);

}
 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,500);
    }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{   

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        y = y + 5;
        repaint();
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        x = x - 5;
        repaint();
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        y = y - 5;
        repaint();
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        x = x + 5;
        repaint();
    }

}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}




public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

this.g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.drawRect(x, y, width, height);

}

}
```

Test class

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;






public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Rectangle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add( new Rectangle(40,20,250,250));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to add `super.paintComponent(g);` that is breaking the flow.

This is working fine with your code by making single line changes.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // add this line

    this.g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawRect(x, y, width, height);

}
```

Please read more about [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can think in other way, you don't have to paint the parent component.

Before call to drawRect, you can clear the old one calling to [clearRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). You must save the dimension and postion of the current rectangle.